# Parallel computation using big matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlabpool

I have a big matrix M (size like 18000 x 18000) and an array k of size

```
k =[k_1,..,k_{100*50}]
```

a small matrix C (like 18000 x 100)

and an iterator

```
iIterator = [1,...,100]
```

I do several computations like this

```
bestValue = inf
parfor i = iIterator

    for j = 1:50
      thing = computeSomething(C(:,1:i),k(i+j))
      value = evalThing(thing,M);
      if value < bestValue
           bestValue = value;
           best_i_Idx = i;
      end 

end
```

Now if M is large I get memory problems, since its copied to each local worker. However M is not changed.

Question :

1) How can I avoid local copies of M ?

2) Which is the best parallel structure for such an algorithm ?

3) I read about memmapfile. Is it possible to use it for that purpose ? So lets say, I save M to a file

```
 mValues.dat
```

Then I could pass each worker the object

```
m=memmapfile('mValues.dat','Format',{'double', [18000 18000],'x'})
```

But once I access it via

```
value = evalThing(thing,m.Data.x);
```

isn't that the same as giving each worker a copy in memory ? So does the worker produce a local copy of the matrix ?

Comment: http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/79428-matrix-operations-with-parallel-computing-toolbox should help you, if this meets your needs, I can post the link as an answer

Comment: you link to mathworks where they explain that matrix operations are already multithreaded. However, here the costs are not produced by some simple matrix multiplications but by the function 'computeSomething' that does some complicated stuff.

Comment: well, you seem to have done the test ... did you notice any difference in memory consumption ? Even without parallel computing consideration, The `memmapfile` are great for reduced memory usage, because they are just a "pointer" to the actual data (on disk). I would hope they bring the same benefit in parfor loops, but I wouldn't be sure before I'd try ... which you did. Now also consider how much of `M` is needed in the `evalThing()` function. If you need to compare a value versus every element of `M` (as opposed to just a small subset), then the `memmapfile` may not be that useful...